# how to install pdo and pdo-mysql in centos via ssh or cpanel?

Tags: php, drupal, pear, cpanel

the problem that i want to use drupal 7.8 and it require pdo and i am not the root
so when i try to install it from pear gives me an error 
i tried many thing but nothing worked

but if any one have any solution for me or the root share it with us

thnx

the pear error message

"Failed loading /usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-4.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so:  /usr/local/Zend/lib/Optimizer-4.3.9/php-5.2.x/ZendOptimizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in Config.php on line 1252
PHP Warning:  base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 1252

Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 1252

Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in Config.php on line 1252
PHP Warning:  base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 1252

Warning: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Config.php on line 1252

Warning: php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons in Registry.php on line 814
PHP Warning:  php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Registry.php on line 814

Warning: php_uname() has been disabled for security reasons in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Registry.php on line 814
0"

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your server admin to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to enable PDO

Open WHM and go to Home » Software » Easy Apache (Apache Update)

Scroll to the bottom and select "Start customizing based on profile"

Click "Next step" twice

Scroll to the bottom and select "Exhaustive Options List"

Select checkboxes for PDO and PDO MySQL, and rebuild Apache

This might be a good time to restart Apache using terminal (# service httpd restart). Hope that helps!